# QTP cannot select data in drop down if more than 50

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I've been looking for answers and try so many ways. I need to automate one websites and this country field have 230 data. When I try to run the script, if the data less then 50 it can select easily. But if I want to select data from 50 onward it only scroll down until the last data. This is my code im using now. Working fine if the data that I want to select in the first 50 range

```
ObjPage. WebElement(xpath="some xpath data" ). Click
ObjPage. WebList("xpath=" some xpath data" ). Selecr strcountry
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the data is already populated in the weblist or is it populating as and when user is scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

most probably the list items are loaded asynchronously(lazy loading) with AJAX, on-demand. Your best try is to look up in javascript / ask the developer about the events that make the list load the rest of the values. If this is clear, send those events to the list via UFT to trigger the loading
(Under the hood you could try calling the Javascript method directly with some runJS commands, however the event based solution is more realistic)